# Azure DevOp - Set Screen Resolution interactive mode

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Due to fact that my VM is opening in small resolution I've been facing lots of situations with flaky tests, mainly about "Element is not clickable" notification. The solution to my problem might be adding extensions and increase the resolution: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task

The problem is I don't exactly know where it should be placed inside my pipeline which looks like this:
[image: My pipeline v.1]

[image: My pipeline v.2]

In order to run successfully this extensions there is a need to fulfill requirements:

- Agent must be configured to run as an interactive process with autologin enabled (Where I should enable that?)

Shall I configure it directly by the "Demands" section on mine "Restart" agent options? I've tried putting the extensions inside the "Restart" section between "Stop" and "Start" agent tasks but it failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reconfig your agent to interactive mode(check below detailed steps), or install a new agent and config it to interactive mode on your VM. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent) to install a new self hosted agent and check for more configuration.

1,

To reconfig your agent to interative mode, you need cd to the agent installation folder and run`.\config remove` to remove it first as shown in below pic.[image]

2,

After agent is removed, Run `.\config` to reconfig your agent, and choose `interactive` during the configuration. Please refer to below screenshot and be careful to choose the right option (Y/N) at the highlighted steps

[image]

3,
To start the interactive agent by run `.\run`

Above steps should be ran as administrator. I followed above steps and successfully run set screen resolution task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you tell me if extensions about Screen resolution is placed in correct way? I'm receiving an error: The term 'query' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

Comment: The extension can be placed just before `vs test task` in run tests section. which task did error come from?

Comment: The error came directly from the resolution extension

Comment: Is there a way to check if my agent works in interactive mode?